# Trouble with installing everpad for lucid

Tags: installation, 10.04, notes

I wanted to install everpad found in ppa ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa  as written in http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/use-evernote-in-ubuntu-with-everpad

Adding repo seems succesful:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
   Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-    keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring  /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 01E7E3EDE399A2252D12CD719A29122E9C8631BA
   gpg: requesting key 9C8631BA from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com 
   gpg: key 9C8631BA: "Launchpad PPA for nvbn" not changed
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

But trying to install fails:

```
sudo apt-get install everpad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package everpad
```

Is this a problem with the ppa or am I doing something wrong. Any steps I could take to get clues on what might be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: everpad is not available for ubuntu 10 ie. no package for lucid is available in the repository

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to add the PPA  [ `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa`]
2. Then update your repository list [`sudo apt-get update`]
3. Then install the package. [`sudo apt-get install everpad`]

You skipped number 2. It is worth noting that the package is only available for 12.10, 12.04  and 11.10.

Comment: i did step 2, but still i have the problem.. i am using ubuntu 10.04 as well..

Comment: The package is only available for the latest 3 releases: Quantal, Precise and Oneiric.

Comment: @Uri, I am using Lubuntu 12.10, I installed everpad, but I am not able to sync. Could Lubuntu be an issue?